# what is the difference between secondary index and non-clustered index

Tags: database, non-clustered-index, secondary-indexes

I'm studying about indexes in a database and I'm having some ambiguity. In a non-clustered index, we learned that the datafiles are not sorted and that each index entry points to a record in the datafile. However, the secondary index doesn't seem to be any different from this one. Can the two be considered the same? If not, I'd appreciate it if you could let me know which one is different.

Comment: You might want to also narrow down to a particular RDBMS, as terminology can vary slightly from product to product.

Comment: sorry. I'm not learning indexes for a specific dbms right now, I'm just taking a general class on indexes. Thanks for the reply

Comment: In general, they are the same. There May be an RDBMS where there is a difference, but I think it would be a bit of an oddity.